# Vim: What is a key code?

Tags: vim

Sorry for the blatant display of ignorance, but what exactly *is* a key code? I'm setting the timeout length in my vimrc, and reading about timeoutlen and ttimeoutlen. There's a distinction between key-mappings and key codes, but I'm not clear what a key code is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On my keyboard, when I type in QWERTY, when I press the "H" key, I get an "H." In contrast, when I'm in Dvorak mode and I press the "H" key, I get a "D." The keyboard is sending the exact same *key-code* to the computer, but the computer *maps* the key to a different letter based on the typing mode (in this case, QWERTY vs Dvorak).

In this example, the *key-code* for the "H" key on the keyboard is 0x48, or "72" in decimal. The *key mapping* is determined by the software (the OS, the text editor, the game, etc) to determine what key-code maps to what function.